# Run 3 threads and wait in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to write a class that can only run X(Let's say 3)threads at one time. I have 8 threads that need to execute but I only want to allow 3 to run at once, then wait.  Once one of the currently running threads stops, then it will start another.  I'm not quite sure how to do this.  My code looks like this:

```
public class Main {
  public void start() {
    for(int i=0; i<=ALLTHREADS; i++) {
      MyThreadClass thread = new MyThreadClass(someParam, someParam);
      thread.run();

      // Continue until we have 3 running threads, wait until a new spot opens up.  This is what I'm having problems with
    }
  }
}

public class MyThreadClass implements Runnable {
  public MyThreadClass(int param1, int param2) {
    // Some logic unimportant to this post
  }

  public void run() {
    // Generic code here, the point of this is to download a large file
  }
}
```

As you can see above most of it is stubbed out pseudo-code.  I can post it if anyone would like but it's unimportant to the main question.

Comment: You should rename MyThreadClass to something else:  It is not a Thread.  The code in your example does not create _any_ threads:  All it does is to serially invoke the run() method a number of times in the program's main thread.  If you want to create a new thread, you must either create a new Thread object and call its start() method, or else you must call a library routine that will do it for you (e.g., as in the answers below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should use thread pooling mechanism here to run multiple threads.

to make it easy we can go for thread pool executor in java which is very easy

create a fixed pool of 3 threads using executors method.

write a for loop for 8 iteration and call execute on each thread and it will run only 3 threads at a time.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
             Task task = new Task(someParam, someParam);
            executor.execute(task);
          }
        executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: (Almost) perfect answer. Improvement suggestion: rename "MyThreadClass" to "Task" and "thread" to "task" to clearly distinguish between tasks (things to run) and threads (how to run things).

Comment: @isnot2bad : i have done the suggested changes and updated the answer...thanks for the suggestion..

Comment: It's worth noting that this will have a total of 4 threads. The 3 executor threads and the initial one (which won't do much)

Answer (score 6):

Unless this is homework, you can use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)` which returns an `ExecutorService` with a max of 3 threads to perform `Runnable` tasks.

Comment: Nope not homework, just working on a little side project to learn :)  Thanks, I'll try it out :)

Comment: @user2229544 You should also remember that besides the threads you create JVM runs several threads by itself.